# Cropping map extent in QGIS2Web?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web

I am new to using QGIS and I have been trying to build a Map which will eventually be put on my firm's website with overlaying layers for different indicators in the local area.

I have made a draft map with OS open background and 16 interchangeable layers using QGIS2Web. However, it is taking around 6-8 minutes to load and is very slow.

I think this is due to the size of the underlaying OS map? Does anyone know how to crop the extent of the map in QGIS2Web?

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/579). Especially [the @Tom Chadwin reply](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/579#issuecomment-345284250).

Comment: @AoifeL The similar discussion was here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/303628/9904

Comment: Thanks you! Both useful comments, I have now changed the background to an XYZ tile - does anyone know how to crop this tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be right that the OS background map could be causing the problem. I don't know the dataset. Is it raster or vector? You would be better off trying to add an XYZ tileserver map for your background. What that means is that, rather than export the whole background map, a link to the remote online source of the XYZ tiles is used.

The first step is to confirm that the OS layer is the one causing the issue. Remove it temporarily from your project, and then export using qgis2web. If it all speeds up, this is the cause.

Comment: This question may be of use: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65244/openlayers-with-uk-ordnance-survey-maps A little old but outlines some options for getting OS layers from the web.

Comment: Hi this was helpful, i have also lowered the precision and this helped!

I am using a XYZ tile now and it is working better, however I can't limit the extent of the map when i create a map using QGIS2WEB I can still zoom out to include the whole world. is there a way I can crop the xyz tile?

Comment: In the qgis2web dialog box, under Appearance > Scale/Zoom, tick "Restrict to extent".